# Login flow in app

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I made the login flow without any reference to a tutorial. So I want some feedback.

Basically it sends username and password in a POST request to /token. The app stores the tokens on device, then uses the auth token to request customer profile data.

**LoginPageViewModel**

```cs
public class LoginPageViewModel
{
    public LoginPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRepository repository, IProperties properties, ITokenService tokenService, ICustomerService customerService, ISubscriptionService subscriptionService, ITicketService ticketService, ITranslationService translation, IUserDialogs dialogs, IConfiguration configuration, IConnectivity connectivity)
    {
        _navigation = navigationService;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _repository = repository;
        _properties = properties;
        _tokenService = tokenService;
        _customerService = customerService;
        _translation = translation;
        _dialogs = dialogs;

        eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoggedInEvent>().Subscribe(async () => await LoggedInEventHandler());
    }

    private readonly INavigationService _navigation;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly IProperties _properties;
    private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;
    private readonly ITranslationService _translation;
    private readonly IUserDialogs _dialogs;

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public ICommand LoginCommand => new Command(async () => await Login());

    private async Task LoggedInEventHandler()
    {
        if (_navigation.GetCurrentPageName() == "LoginPage")
        {
            await _navigation.NavigateAsync("/MainMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/ContentPage");
        }
    }

    private async Task Login()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password))
        {
            return;
        }

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoggingInEvent>().Publish();

        TokenData getTokenResponse;

        try
        {
            getTokenResponse = await _tokenService.GetTokens(Username, Password);
        }
        catch (BadRequestException)
        {
            _dialogs.Alert(_translation.GetString("ProfilePageInvalidUsernameOrPassword"));
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginFailedEvent>().Publish();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _dialogs.Alert(_translation.GetString("ProfilePageOtherFault"));

            Crashes.TrackError(ex, new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Event", "LoginAndGetTokens" },
                { "Subject", Username },
                { "Message", ex.Message },
            });

            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginFailedEvent>().Publish();
            return;
        }

        _properties.AccessToken = getTokenResponse.AccessToken;
        _properties.AccessTokenExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(getTokenResponse.ExpiresIn);
        _properties.RefreshToken = getTokenResponse.RefreshToken;

        try
        {
            var getCustomerResponse = await _customerService.GetCustomer(_properties.AccessToken);
            _repository.Customer = getCustomerResponse.Customer;

            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CustomerRetrievedEvent>().Publish(getCustomerResponse.Customer);
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoggedInEvent>().Publish();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _dialogs.Alert(_translation.GetString("ProfilePageOtherFault"));

            Crashes.TrackError(ex, new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Event", "GetCustomerAfterLogin" },
                { "Subject", Username },
                { "Message", ex.Message }
            });

            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginFailedEvent>().Publish();
        }
    }
}
```

**TokenService**

```cs
public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
    public TokenService(IRequestService requestService)
    {
        _requestService = requestService;
    }

    private readonly IRequestService _requestService;

    public Task<TokenData> GetTokens(string loginName, string password)
    {
        var getTokenRequest = new RestRequest("token", Method.POST);

        getTokenRequest.AddParameter("client_id", "XamarinApp", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        getTokenRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "password", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        getTokenRequest.AddParameter("username", loginName, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        getTokenRequest.AddParameter("password", password, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

        return _requestService.DoRequest<TokenData>(getTokenRequest);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class TokenData
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public long ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("as:client_id")]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("userName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**RequestService**

```cs
public class RequestService : IRequestService
{
    private readonly IConnectivity _connectivity;
    private readonly IRestClient _restClient;

    public RequestService(IConnectivity connectivity, IRestClient restClient)
    {
        _connectivity = connectivity;
        _restClient = restClient;
    }

    public async Task<TResult> DoRequest<TResult>(IRestRequest request)
    {
        if (!_connectivity.IsConnected)
        {
            throw new NoConnectionException();
        }

        var response = await _restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync<TResult>(request);

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedException(response.Content);
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                throw new BadRequestException(response.Content);
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                throw new NotFoundException(response.Content);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException(response.Content);
            }
        }

        return response.Data;
    }
}
```

Example response when POST to /token

```
{
    "access_token": "-UHguElQMme12_aIQ305C5pFBwV1X-qAyT1rO2quJcqXIjOCwd73kAwAVCiyfIsThoWa8LPgVmTOyBWG0rBa_5GsaAt8w-O2njL8SNBEJQma47IlGsL53jGJzAVfy2xk37GJLdmkvYOQRZF3u_ejOEx0XhYUNxg-Ph2IjV5EMgTWXrUjoUbiw8V7feonH1QpDFjgN7sZrDcKsLqzG0900yUVaqliCwPmSe6pcfa7ybEHyBG8KC7rihWqNcwMOx9yfwbDVAVY0ZzOJaNT0k0G1sRu0t4KHKr28I7EW_R-zCQVHVCq5uimYcL1VDJRzbNRz83GUddXT6OmQfW5PjTmUYqAPMl3JcyBkv5ko4R0kHB9v0Yp_Sb-4oJasOraF6c3wdqpXJAUTxIHGZy6WIeXJRwr1ZuFmngx_eiUafPsKxEcTTyvPmgPkV36FHam9FBl",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 86399,
    "refresh_token": "210a2106fd564aee9a75daeb73458fa2",
    "as:client_id": "XamarinApp",
    "userName": "someone@example.com",
    ".issued": "Wed, 01 May 2019 10:10:06 GMT",
    ".expires": "Thu, 02 May 2019 10:10:06 GMT"
}
```

The Web API was setup according to *[Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your RequestService by inverting the if-statement in DoRequest():

```
public async Task<TResult> DoRequest<TResult>(IRestRequest request)
{
    if (!_connectivity.IsConnected)
    {
        throw new NoConnectionException();
    }

    var response = await _restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync<TResult>(request);

    // If Ok, return ...
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return response.Data;
    }

    // ... so this block is not nested
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedException(response.Content);
    }
    else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        throw new BadRequestException(response.Content);
    }
    else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(response.Content);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException(response.Content);
    }
}
```

Since you always compare the status code, make sure to use a switch statement. This results in much shorter and more readable code.

```
public async Task<TResult> DoRequest<TResult>(IRestRequest request)
{
    if (!_connectivity.IsConnected)
    {
        throw new NoConnectionException();
    }

    var response = await _restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync<TResult>(request);

    switch (response.StatusCode)
    {
        case HttpStatusCode.OK:
            return response.Data;
        case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
            throw new UnauthorizedException(response.Content);
        case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
            throw new BadRequestException(response.Content);
        case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            throw new NotFoundException(response.Content);
        default:
            throw new HttpRequestException(response.Content);
    }
}
```